# JavaFX - Change color of blue line when dragging TableColumn in a TableView

Tags: css, javafx, scenebuilder

Every time I drag a column, I get a blue line across the whole column. <s>I know I can remove it by setting `-fx-background-insets: 0;`, but I can't figure out where to put it.</s>  This line appears **only** when I'm dragging it, if I'm not doing it, everything is fine.

[image: dragging]

**My current `CSS` is as follows:**

```
.table-view .column-header,
.table-view .filler,
.table-view .column-header-background .show-hide-columns-button {
    -fx-background-color: white;
}
.table-view .column-header {    
    -fx-border-color: grey;
    -fx-border-width: 0 1 0 0;
}
.table-view .column-header-background { 
    -fx-border-color: grey;
    -fx-border-width: 0 0 1 0;
}
.table-view .show-hide-column-image {
    -fx-background-color: black;
}
.table-view .column-drag-header,
.table-view .column-overlay {
    -fx-background-color: green;
}
.table-view:focused > .virtual-flow > .clipped-container > .sheet > .table-row-cell:filled:selected,
.table-view:focused > .virtual-flow > .clipped-container > .sheet > .table-row-cell .table-cell:selected {
    -fx-background-color: darkgrey;
    -fx-table-cell-border-color: grey;
}
.table-cell {
    -fx-border-color: grey;
    -fx-border-width: 0 1 0 0;
    -fx-text-fill: black;
}
.table-row-cell:focused {
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
}
.table-row-cell:selected .table-cell {
    -fx-text-fill: black;
}
```

The only thing I see about this "drag-event" in `modena.css` is this:

```
/* When a column is being 'dragged' to be placed in a different position, there
   is a region that follows along the column header area to indicate where the
   column will be dropped. This region can be styled using the .column-drag-header
   name. */
.table-view .column-drag-header,
.tree-table-view .column-drag-header {
    -fx-background: -fx-accent;
    -fx-background-color: -fx-selection-bar;
    -fx-border-color: transparent;
    -fx-opacity: 0.6;
}
/* Semi-transparent overlay to indicate the column that is currently being moved */
.table-view .column-overlay,
.tree-table-view .column-overlay {
    -fx-background-color: darkgray;
    -fx-opacity: 0.3;
}
```

<s>I tried putting it in both places like so:</s>

```
.table-view .column-drag-header,
.table-view .column-overlay {
    -fx-background-insets:0;
}
```

But it had no effect.

I thought maybe this "region" is the one that has insets and it's because of it that the blue line appears, but I couldn't find where it is or at least what's it called in the `CSS`.

**Edit:** changed the question to "changing the color" instead of removing it, since it seems like a better approach. Solution for changing the color was provided by **kleopatra** in the comments.

```
.table-view .column-resize-line {
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: why? the line is a visual hint where the column will be located why would you want to deprive the users of that hint?

Comment: @kleopatra Because the colour doesn't go with the visual style of my application.

Comment: then change the color - look into modena.css and/or the sources to find the rule

Comment: @kleopatra If I knew which class contains the line to change it's colour, I wouldn't be asking in the first place because, most likely, it would be the same place where I'm supposed to put `-fx-background-insets: 0;`. I've Googled a lot and I've gone through the `modena.css` extensively numerous times for hours now, but obviously I'm missing something.

Comment: after a cursory look, the owner of the line is tableViewSkinBase and its style is column-resize-line

Comment: at the end of the day not every detail is properly documented - looking into the source helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Modena.css, the CSS class `.column-resize-line` can be used for both `TableView` and `TreeTableView`:

```css
/* The column-resize-line is shown when the user is attempting to resize a column. */
.table-view .column-resize-line,
.tree-table-view .column-resize-line {
    -fx-background: -fx-accent;
    -fx-background-color: -fx-background;
    -fx-padding: 0.0em 0.0416667em 0.0em 0.0416667em; /* 0 0.571429 0 0.571429 */
}
```